# i7 6700k performing at the very bottom of benchmark test

Tags: 64-bit, intel-core-i7

Last year I built a computer (for the first time) and though I was happy it worked from the first power on, I was never impressed by the speed (comparing it to my 5 year old system). I started looking into it further and it is clear I have some problem with the CPU. For whatever reason, I am at the very bottom of any benchmarks I run.

I uploaded a bunch of screenshots test to https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzWsuGkUzC3FXzJ4OGU2Y... including test from Lightroom where I HDR merged 5 images to one HDR, 3 HDR processes at the time. You can see that the CPU utilization was at 100% couple of times.

I have checked the CPU temperature in the past, and now again, but seems like it maxes at 32C.

I do think somewhere I messed up seeing the results of the tests, given I am lower than low. YOu can see it on the screenshot from the Intel Extreme Tuning utility. The computer is slow even when browsing, editing images, videos, etc. (Adobe suite is my main activity on this PC).

Based on the test all seems adequate, but clearly, the CPU is the problem. And yes, when putting in the new paste, I did wipe the old one off ;-)

Is it possible the CPU is damaged?

I updated BIOS so that should be up to date. Not sure where to go from here. Any pointers?

Comment: Try cpuid hwmonitor. btw. the link to your screenshots doesn't work.

Comment: "Is it possible the CPU is damaged?" - It is possible but unlikely.

Comment: Sorry, here is the updated link to the screenshots https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzWsuGkUzC3FXzJ4OGU2YjRVd3c  I added a screenshot from the monitor. I don't see much besides one temperature on the motherboard is 127C.  OK, found out that is the default so that should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

Your CPU runs at only 800 MHz instead of 4GHz. So everything runs 5 times slower than it should. That's because your CPU multiplier is set to 8 instead of 40. You can change that in the BIOS.

You should probably reset your BIOS settings to default values because there could be other incorrect settings there. This is explained in the [motherboard  manual](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z170A-GAMING-M5.html#down-manual) on page 44.

But you may want to save/print out the current bios configuration before changing it. According to the manual you can take screenshots with F12.